# Print values from dictionary

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
static void showSetsFunction(){
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> aux in definitions){
        Console.WriteLine(aux.Key+"->"+aux.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

And the output of that is this:
[image: console]

How can I do correctly?

Comment: Code is correct and your expectations are not. If you expect something different from type names printed by code shown in the post you need to explicitly specify that in the post. (Side note: avoid posting images when regular text would work).

Comment: FYI: `ToString` on a `List<T>` is not implemented in any way you would typically want to use (hence the `Systems.Collections`... you see)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string.Join` to turn your list of strings into a comma separated string.

```
Console.WriteLine(aux.Key + "->" + string.Join(", ", aux.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

`aux.Value` is a `List<string>`, not a `string`. You can easily fix this by reducing the list to a single `string` with `string.Join` for example:

```
static void showSetsFunction(){

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> aux in definitions){
        Console.WriteLine(aux.Key+"->"+string.Join(",", aux.Value.ToArray()));
    }

}
```

Comment: `ToArray` is not needed as `string.Join` has an overload that takes `IEnumerable<string>`